# remove values in list using logical operators

Tags: python, list

Just would like to ask how can I masked or remove the values in my list based on logical operators.

Here is the case:

I converted an NDVI.img file into a 1 dimensional array. and as part of the preprocessing, I would like to remove NDVI values in my array that are less than 0.3 and greater than 0.8. Values greater than and equal to 0.3 to 0.8 are only my interest.

Comment: Take a look at Python list comprehensions. An example might be: [a for a in yourlist if (a.NDVI >= 0.3 and a.NDVI <= 0.8)] An alternative is to use multiple `if` statements: [a for a in yourlist if a.NDVI >= 0.3 if a.NDVI <= 0.8)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanted to use numpy you could convert the list to an array and use [logical operators](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) --

```
import numpy as np
# your list
a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7. 0.9]
a = np.array(a)

a[np.logical_and(a>=0.3,a<0.8)]

>>>array[0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7])
```

or if you wanted to convert the unwanted values to nan (or some other value), but retain the shape of the array - perhaps something like

```
a[np.logical_or(a<0.3, a>0.8)] = np.nan

>>>array([nan, nan, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, nan])
```

Comment: Thanks fluidmotion. Can you suggest a technique how to replace the nan values to null or some type to exclude it in any statistical computation. Thanks very much.

Comment: it may depend on the statistic you would like to run - some numpy functions work fine with nan values (np.nanmean, np,nanmedian, etc.). Of course, the first option above leaves out any nan and nulls - so they would not be an issue. if you have an example of the type of analysis, it might make a good follow up question (although it could get bumped to stack overflow, which might be more appropriate).

Comment: Hi Fluidmotion and @Richard Morgan, actually I am trying to run a scikit module -- slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(vNdvi,vLst) --. All the statistical computation gives me a nan result. Thanks, -Leo

Comment: might try a mask as suggested at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643363/linear-regression-of-arrays-containing-nans-in-python-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Python [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

An example might be:

```
[a for a in yourlist if (a.NDVI >= 0.3 and a.NDVI <= 0.8)]
```

Another popular way to write these is with multiple `if` statements:

```
[a for a in yourlist if a.NDVI >= 0.3 if a.NDVI <= 0.8)]
```

I had use the first one because I misread your requirements and used an `or` to remove the range rather than select it.